# How do I disable local notification sound when app is active?

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose that my app is active but as soon as the app enters UIApplicationWillResignActive mode then the local notification fires. This is a problem for me because if the app is locked but is still active it will enter UIApplicationWillResignActive but the NSTimer which has sound will fire along with the local notification sound!

Comment: Why are you using NSTimer to play sound file? What is your actual purpose?

Comment: I'm making an alarm clock app. If the user leaves the app running in foreground through NSTimer there will be an alarm sound played with no limitations. Here's more information in detail: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/